# Update date +2 mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have this procedure. It works but what i need is that instead of `puntos = 5`, it adds `+2` puntos to what is in the DB. How could I do it?

Example:

[Photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TZH9.png)

Procedure:

```
    delimiter $$
create procedure select_or_insert()

begin

  IF EXISTS (select * from result_equipo where id_eq = '27') THEN

    update result_equipo set puntos = 5 where id_eq = '27';

  ELSE 

    insert into result_equipo (id_reseq, id_div, jor, id_eq, puntos, pg, 

pp, n_p, fecha) VALUES 

(NULL, '25', '3', '27', '2', '1', '0', '0', '2018-05-05');

  END IF;
end $$
delimiter ;

call select_or_insert();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can modify the update statement like this -

```
update result_equipo set puntos = puntos+2 where id_eq = '27';
```